# If $G$ has central Sylow $2$-subgroup, then it has normal $2$-complement.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. If $G$ has a central Sylow $2$-subgroup, then $G$ has a normal $2$-complement.

Why is this so? Do you have a proof of this fact?

Comment: Hmm, so I can easily find a proof, but that uses Burnside's transfer theorem, which might be overkill. Are you familiar with that result?

Comment: No, not yet. But if there is no more elementary proof I would be glad if you post it or a reference.

Comment: I recall seeing this being an exercise in some textbook, presented just after Sylow theory, so there ought to be a more elementary proof of it. I just don't know one.

Comment: Or you could prove the result when the Sylow 2-subgroup has order two, and use induction.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Yes that works! When the Sylow $2$-subgroup has order $2$ you can do it by intersecting the image of the regular permutation representation with the alternating group.

Answer (score 0):

If Sylow-$2$ subgroup is central, then it is normal also, and its order is coprime to its index in the group. By [Schur-Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem), the Sylow-$2$ subgroup, $P$ has complement $K$, hence $$G=P\rtimes K.$$
But since $P$ is *central* subgroup, it normalizes $K$ also, hence $K$ is normal (complement).

Comment: But Chris Godsil has shown that there is an elementary proof that avoids using Schur-Zassenhaus ord Transfer.

Comment: yes; there is; question was about "proof".